# Windows SDK Wont Install (Old version allegedly exists)

Tags: windows, sdk

I am trying to get an old version of the windows sdk to download but I may have messed up the removal of previous versions (uninstalling the entire Windows Kits folder instead of running an uninstaller).

It doesn't let me install any version of the sdk, except from the Visual Studio Installer that doesn't work for my needs. I tried the Iso they provide and the installer with no luck, same error message in attachment.

OS: Windows 11

Target SDK: 19041.685.201201-2105

[image]